# Sum formulas for Pontrjagin square and Postnikov square

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

Inspire by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/59593/27004), I wonder

**Pontrjagin square**: There is a geometric interpretation of $\mathfrak{P}_2$, due to Morita.

Assume $q=2k$, so that the Pontrjagin square is a map 
$$\mathfrak{P}_2 \colon H^{2k}(X, \mathbb{Z}_2) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4.$$ Set $$Z \equiv \sum_{t \in H^{2k}(X, \mathbb{Z}_2)} e^{2 \pi i \mathfrak{P}_2(t)}.$$ Then

> $$\textrm{Arg}(Z)= \textrm{Arg}( \sum_{t \in H^{2k}(X, \mathbb{Z}_2)} e^{2 \pi i \mathfrak{P}_2(t)})= \frac{\sigma(M)}{8} \in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, \tag{(a)}$$

where $\sigma(X)$ denotes the signature of $M$.

For a proof, see [*Gauss Sums in Algebra and Topology*](http://www.nd.edu/~taylor/papers/Gauss_sums.pdf), by Laurence R. Taylor.

**Postnikov square**:

> Question: Are there similar statements for Postnikov square? (like eqn.(a))

Postnikov square is a certain cohomology operation from a first cohomology group $H^1$ to a third cohomology group $H^3$, introduced by Postnikov (1949). Eilenberg (1952) described a generalization taking classes in $H^t$ to $H^{2t+1}$.

Refs:

- Postnikov, M. M. (1949), "The classification of continuous mappings of a three-dimensional polyhedron into a simply connected polyhedron of arbitrary dimension", Doklady Akademii Nauk SSSR (N.S.) (in Russian), 64: 461–462
- Eilenberg, Samuel (1952), "Homotopy groups and algebraic homology theories", Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians, Cambridge, Massachusetts, 1950, vol. 2, Providence, R.I.: Amer. Math. Soc., pp. 350–353, MR 0045388